# Factor analysis without listwise deletion

Tags: r, factor-analysis, missing-data, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor

Can factor analysis be done in a manner which affords missingness on some items?

- With what methods can a factor analysis be performed in which subjects who are missing on one or two items are retained, and a score for each subject for each factor can be computed?
- Are there recommended methods for creating those factor scores, given missingness?

(Analyses will be performed on R, and the factor analysis will need to accommodate items on different scales.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing confirmatory factor analysis using `R` and the `lavaan` package your can specify 'fiml' (full information maximum likelihood) in the missing option. Like so:

```
fit <- cfa(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939, 
           std.lv=TRUE,  
           missing="fiml")
```

This was taken from: http://www.understandingdata.net/2017/03/22/cfa-in-lavaan/